# How to store a HTML file to a list? Not as attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365

I noticed that there are some HTML / ASPX files that are tied to the SharePoint list, which makes the file's URL to be: `https://<path>/Lists/<ListName>/<FileName>.html` or `https://<path>/Lists/<ListName>/<FileName>.aspx`

However, if I were to open the list's properties in SharePoint Designer to search for this file, it is neither a new **View** or **Form** page.
[image]

Also, the HTML file is not attached to the list item as an attachment. So, I was wondering how is this done? How do you create additional webpages to the list? Is it via SharePoint Designer? Or..?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These "files" usually lives in your content database. That's why you can't find the actual files in an on-premise environment.

The **Views** shows a **list of items** in "prescribed order and selections". This means that you use the views to display list data the way you want, by date, by author, by title, by category. It can be grouped, sorted and filtered in almost endless combinations.

The **Forms** are used to **display a single item** with the properties you want. You can also edit an items properties using a form.

You can edit both views and forms using the browser, SharePoint Designer, Visual Studio or any other text editor. It depends what you prefer and what you're trying to accomplish. Use the tool best suited for the task at hand.

*Hint*: Click the "New"-button in the Views and Forms section of SharePoint Designer and explore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason why I asked this question is because I noted that some developers who had left, were referencing these files on the Content Editor. And that's how I found out that you can actually add HTML/ASPX to the list itself... but how?

As my environment is on Office 365, I doubt the developers can create these files on the Content Database. So, I'm trying to recreate this file, in a similar manner of storing, and tried to Google around for it but to no avail.

Comment: @Kodeist Hope the answer helps, and that you can solve the issue at hand!

Comment: Hi Benny, I tried to click the "New" button on the 'Views' and 'Forms' section, the result isn't the same as what we are looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Kodeist Usually the browser is best for creating views, and Visual studio for creating forms.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to figure out the location of these files after checking around and literally missed the path.

**The Steps**

1. In **Internet Explorer**, access any library on the site to open up the library in file explorer. Click the **Open In Explorer** button on the SharePoint ribbon.
2. When the file explorer opens, click on the folder 'Lists' to access the folders of all the lists available on the site.
   [image: The 'Lists' folder in the file explorer.[1]]
3. Then, access your desired list and you should be able to view all the files, the **Attachments** and **Item** folders, **View** and **Form** pages within. You can also store HTML/ASPX files into this location to make the file *belong* to the list, specifically.